# I want to optionally concatenate n columns in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to concatenate few columns in the following manner.

say the table is like this.

| id | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | true | false |
| 2 | true | false | false |
| 3 | false | true | false |

Result:

| id | column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | column1, column2 |
| 2 | column1 |
| 3 | column2 |

So, I want to know how to do something like this in SQL. I prefer PostgreSQL 8, but any SQL is fine if it's convertible to Postgres. Please mention the version in the answer.
Thanks.

Comment: There was no "PostgreSQL 8" - there were **five** different major versions of the 8.x line - all of them dead and forgotten. You shouldn't use it at all. In fact all versions before Postgres 11 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `concat_ws()` and `case` for that.

```
select
    id,
    concat_ws(
      ', ',
      case when column1 then 'column1' else null end,
      case when column2 then 'column2' else null end,
      case when column3 then 'column3' else null end
    ) as "column"
from MyTable;
```

The `concat_ws` function concatenates non-null values (first argument is a separator). The `case` expression helps to get some value based on another value, so you can return either null or a column name as an argument for `concat_ws` based on the column value.